# Cannot install gcp profiler on node 18.14.0 , "Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof/build/node-v108-linux-x64-glibc/pprof.node""

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to install profiler on cloud run service where I am getting error when I deploy the build Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof/build/node-v108-linux-x64-glibc/pprof.node' , Where I am using macOs and the file i have is Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/node_modules/pprof/build/node-v108-darwin-x64-unknown/pprof.node'. Node version I am using is 18.14.0 , Can anyone help me here on how can I solve this and install profiler ?